# Python sqlalchemy returning values after delete

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How to return values after deleting in sqlalchemy.

This is the query I want to achieve:

```sql
DELETE FROM sometable WHERE id = 1 returning id
```

But this is currently what I have:

```py
DBSession.query(SomeTable).filter(SomeTable.id == 1).delete(synchronize_session=False)
```

I need return value from that table after deletion, anyone could help me?

Comment: Unfortunately the ORM query does not support `RETURNING`, but only the count of matching rows. You have to use the Core, if you need that statement.

Comment: Hi Ilja Everilä, you may put this comment to answer.

Answer (score -3):

Just call drop() against the table object. From the docs:

Issue a DROP statement for this Table, using the given Connectable for connectivity.

In your case it should be:

.**table**.drop()
If you get an exception like:

sqlalchemy.exc.UnboundExecutionError: Table object '' is not bound to an Engine or Connection. Execution can not proceed without a database to execute against
You need to pass the engine:

.**table**.drop(engine)